# Jmeter give error "We are sorry but vue-dms-ui-component doesn't work properly witouth Javascript enabled.Please enable it to continue"

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

In Jmeter, I have used "Recording with Think Time" for an application. Now when i run, in the Response I get message "We are sorry but vue-dms-ui-component doesn't work properly witouth Javascript enabled.Please enable it to continue".

I get this message for all the requests. I have enabled JavaScript in Firefox and then captured the recording.

Attaching the screenshot of the message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsYLj.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So it's not possible to "enable" JavaScript in JMeter.

- If JavaScript is being executed on client-side only you can simply ignore this
- If JavaScript generates a single network request - you need to mimic it using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
- If JavaScript generates more than 1 network request at a time - use as many HTTP Request samplers as there are AJAX requests and put them under the [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/parallel-controller-in-jmeter)

Don't forget to perform [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of dynamic parameters as in the vast majority of cases you cannot just replay the recorded network traffic.